# Bind to a MainPage Property out of DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime

I'm trying to bind an object defined in MainPage (CodeBehind) to a ConverterParameter inside a ListView DataTemplate:

```
<ListView ...>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text=".. SomeBindingExpression"
   FontWeight="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ChangeDateToFontWeightConverter},ConverterParameter={Binding Source=MainPage,Path=Cache}}"/>
      </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Goal is to pass the "Cache" - Object defined in MainPage into the Converter. The obove Code calls the converter properly but the passed object Parameter is null. Is there any way to refer the Cache object in this XAML Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ConverterParameter takes a string and can not be databound at all. 
You can add a custom property to the converter class and pass your "Cache"-object in the code-behind of your MainPage.

```
((ChangeDateToFontWeightConverter)this.Resources["ChangeDateToFontWeightConverter"]).MyCustomProperty = myCacheObject;
```

In general i would advise to take an [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651572.aspx) approach and extend your databound class with the required data from the cache object (if possible). That way you won't need the converter at all.

Comment: That approach does the Job! But you're right in extending the databound class. Now I manage the cache-handling in the MainPage and set the needed data in an extended databound class. I don't get rid of the converter, but now it's a "BooleanToFontWeightConverter" - easy. Thanks for removing my "CodeBlindness".